# Actualizar un producto del carrito de compras Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

quiero poder actualizar que cantida se desea en el carrito de compras pero no se en que me falla o que tendria mal soy algo nuevo en laravel y no entiendo el porque sigue sin funcionar

cart.blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title','Carrito de compras')

@section('content')
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Carrito de compras</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cart">
      @if (count($cart))
        <p>
          <a href="{{route('cart-trash')}}" class="btn btn-danger">
            Vaciar carrito <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
          </a>
        </p>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Imagen</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
                <th>Quitar</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <body>
              @foreach ($cart as $item)
                <tr>
                  <td><img src="/images/{{$item->avatar}}" width="50px" height="50px"></td>
                  <td>{{$item->medicamento}}</td>
                  <td>${{number_format($item->precio,2)}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      min="1"
                      max="100"
                      value="{{$item->quantity}}"
                      id="medicamento_{{$item->id}}"
                    >
                    <a
                      href="#"
                      class="btn btn-warning btn-update-item"
                      data-href="{{route('cart-update', $item->id)}}"
                      data-id="{{$item->id}}"
                    >
                          <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>${{number_format($item->precio * $item->quantity,2)}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="{{route('cart-delete', $item->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger">
                      <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              @endforeach
            </body>
          </table><hr>
          <h3>
            <span class="label label-success">
               Total: ${{number_format($total,2)}}
            </span>
          </h3>
        </div>
    @else
      <h3><span class="label label-warning">No hay productos en el carrito</span></h3>
    @endif
    <hr>
    <p>
      <a href="{{route('home')}}" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>Seguir comprando
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
        Hacer Pedido <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
      </a>
    </p>
    </div>
  </div>
@endsection
```

carcontroller en el update:

```
  public function update($id, $quantity)
    {
      $medicamento=Medicamento::find($id);
      $cart= \Session::get('cart');
      $cart[$medicamento->id]->quantity=$quantity;
      return redirect()->route('cart-show');
    }
```

la ruta que estoy manejando:

```
Route::get('cart/update/{farmacia}/quantity',[
  'as'=> 'cart-update',
  'uses' => 'CartController@update'
]);
```

y estoy manejando un script en el app.blade

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer>
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $(".btn-update-item").on('click',function(e){
          e.preventDefault();

          var id=$(this).data('id');
          var href=$(this).data('href');
          var quantity=$('#medicamento_' + id).val();

          window.location.href = href +"/"+ quantity;
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

En la ruta de Laravel no estás definiendo un parámetro sino una constante en `/quantity`

Sería algo así:

```
Route::get('cart/update/{farmacia}/{quantity}',[
  'as'=> 'cart-update',
  'uses' => 'CartController@update'
]);
```

Si la cantidad es opcional, sería `{quantity?}`, el resto ya es manejarlo en el método del controlador.

Más información en: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

---

Teniendo en cuenta que `quantity` es un valor que se define en el lado del cliente, utilizar `route('cart-update', $item->id)` va a dar error porque no se está pasando el segundo parámetro de la ruta, para solucionarlo se puede dejar opcional el segundo valor (ver más arriba) o dejar un valor por defecto y luego reemplazarlo via JavaScript.

Comment: usarlo coo dices ya lo e probado y me da un error.Missing required parameters for [Route: cart-update] [URI: cart/update/{farmacia}/{quantity}]. (View: C:\laragon\www\Farmacia\resources\views\medicamentos\cart.blade.php)

Comment: Tienes dos opciones: una fue la que mostré en la respuesta: que `quantity` sea opcional, con eso no hay problema inicialmente con el helper. La segunda opción es poner un valor por defecto en quantity y reemplazarlo vía JavaScript al momento de hacer clic y tener el nuevo valor de la cantidad.

Comment: el de opcional no me serviria como podria hacerlo cremplazandolo con el JavaScrit

Comment: Cualquiera de los dos sirve, no veo porque al ser opcional no podría servir. Para reemplazar por JavaScript, existe entre otros https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: digo que al ser opcinal no sirve no d nigun error pero no se me actualiza la cantidad del medicamento que quiero

Comment: Un poco de debugging (depuración) le puede ayudar a solucionar los demás errores.